# I've overcomplicated adding variables for my dice roll game

Tags: python

I'm doing a dice roll assignment. The rules are:

- The points rolled on each player’s dice are added to their score.
- If the total is an even number, an additional 10 points are added to their score.
- If the total is an odd number, 5 points are subtracted from their score.
- If they roll a double, they get to roll one extra die and get the number of points rolled added to their score.
- The score of a player cannot go below 0 at any point.
- The person with the highest score at the end of the 5 rounds wins.

Basically, what I've done is created variables of what 2 separate players roll in 2 rounds of the game, now I'm trying to add these variables together so that the player can have their total for round 1 and 2 combined. My teacher had mentioned something about a while function but that was all he was allowed to say, that plus I'm not sure how to do that.

I feel like what I've done is overly complicated, plus the fact it doesn't even work.

```
if (round2scoreP1 % 2) == 0 + (round1scoreP1 % 2) == 0:
    addedscoreround2P1even=(totalround1scoreP1even)+(totalround2scoreP1even)
    print(username1,"'s total for round 1 and 2 is",addedscoreround2P1even,".")
elif (round1scoreP1 % 2) != 0 + (round2scoreP1 % 2) != 0:
    addedscoreround2P1odd=(totalround1scoreodd)+(totalround2scoreodd)
    print(username1,"'s total for round 1 and 2 is",addedscoreround2P1odd,".")
elif (round1scoreP1 % 2) == 0 + (round2scoreP1 % 2) != 0:
    addedscoreround2P1evenodd=(totalround1scoreP1even)+(totalround1scoreP1odd)
    print(username1,"'s total for round 1 and 2 is",addedscoreround2P1evenodd,".")
elif (round1scoreP1 % 2) != 0 + (round2scoreP1 % 2) == 0:
    addedscoreround2P1oddeven=(totalround1scoreP1odd)+(totalround1scoreP1even)
    print(username1," obtained",addedscoreround2P1oddeven,".")
```

Comment: This is too low level to be able to help... Give us the rules of the game, and how you represent the various actors (player, score, roll, etc.), instead of hoping we can reverse engineer your if blocks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write you the whole assignment, but you could consider using a Player-class to store the rolls and total scores in:

```
class Player():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.rolls = []
        self.total_score = 0

    def roll_dice():
        self.rolls.append(random.randint(1, 6))
```